# Can we assign type to a object declared in a variable(modular Programming)

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

Hello I'm trying to assign a type to all the properties(keys) of an object which is declared inside a variable's definition

I've tried declaring the object outside as another variable like below code

```
interface d{
    name: string;
    id: number;
}
var newObject: d={
    name: 'sam',
    id: 1;
}
```

But I want to declare this object inside the variable a which i want to call somewhere else

```
Ex: 
interface d{
    name: string;
    id:number;
}
var a={
    newObject: d: {
        name:'sam',
        id: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a type of a property inside an object literal.

You could declare the type on `a`, without needing a dedicated interface:

```
interface d{
     name: string;
     id:number;
}
var a: { newObject: d }={
    newObject: {
        name:'sam',
        id: 1
    }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCYG8BQyc5HAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5tdlhViQBXAgI2noF9MAbnCjI4pdMhAQA7gHlOAKwgIwpVMl4BeLIylzFy1ch2Nc+IsQDkZQpYA0DU0xbIAjI42ZeQA)

You could use a type assertion, but that will not be as type safe as it will disable some checks:

```
interface d{
     name: string;
     id:number;
}
var a ={
    newObject: {
        name:'sam',
        id: 1,
        randomProp : "" // no err
    } as d
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCYG8BQyc5HAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5tdlhViQBXAgI2noF9MAbnCjI4yALxZGICAHcA8pwBWEBGFJTGufEWIByMoT0AaBlqYtkARlPmcUOCFQB7AgAUozgA7JSAIj9kAHog5BBnZGgoM2ReUTI0TF4gA)

If you need to do this often you might consider a helper function with a generic type parameter, this will be fully typesafe and avoid the extra type as in the first solution:

```
interface d {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
function checked<T>(o: T) { return o; }
var a = {
  newObject: checked<d>({
    name: 'sam',
    id: 1,
    randomProp: "" // err
  })
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCbIN4ChnJHAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4dlhVSQBXAgI2noF8sZWIBGGAB7EMgQALCAgDWEVAB4AKgD4AFKNIqAlJmRQIYVlAmjayPgDc4UZHGQBeTAxAQA7gHkOAK1lgpNKyCsqomti4uPhEpADkZIRxADQMuEykAIypUYZwIKiiBAAKUKIADqQARFXIAPR1yNBQDDy6WDxAA)

**Edit** Answering the question in the comments, if you want to use this for an array, you can pretty much do the same:

**Helper function**

```
interface d {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
function checked<T>(o: T) { return o; }
var a = {
  newObject: checked<d[]>([{
    name: 'sam',
    id: 1,
  }])
}

a.newObject.push({
  id: 2,
  name: ""
});
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCbIN4ChnJHAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4dlhVSQBXAgI2noF8sZWIBGGAB7EMgQALCAgDWEVAB4AKgD4AFKNIqAlJmRQIYVlAmjayPgDc4UZHGQBeTAxAQA7gHkOAK1lgpNKyCsqoANoAuprh2Li4+ESkAORkhMkANAy4TKQAjFm4PJG6WHxYcAB07t5+AZUADqxkUhpxjMzIAEyFeIQkyABEg2W6tEA)

**Type Assertion (ok if array is empty)**

```
interface d{
     name: string;
     id:number;
}
var a ={
    newObject: [] as d[]
}
a.newObject.push({ id: 1, name: "sam"})
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCYG8BQyc5HAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5tdlhViQBXAgI2noF9MAbnCjI4yALxZGICAHcA8pwBWEBGFIBtALqiyabZn5wAdDIXLVYYwAc2ZABYAKdExbIAjABpk+IqQBEZIT+vACUQA)

Comment: can you suggest how I can apply the type 'd' to an array inside the same variable 'a'. the array is gonna be an object array

Comment: I will be adding the elements of the object array later using push command! but initially i want the object array to be of the type d

Comment: @xandercage Either method will work. If the array is empty `[] as d[]` using the cast,  or `checked<T[]>([{ ... }])`

Comment: hello, @Titian Sorry to trouble you again! but could you give a detailed explanation as to how to use the above methodology? I want to use the push function to push the object into the array! all I could do is declare an empty array but I'm not able to assign the type to the array